# что делает минус перед скобкой в delphi

Tags: delphi

есть переменная mask она типа cardinal,
и при её присвоении происходит вот эта:

```
var Mask,Byte : cardinal;

Mask := -(Result and 1);
```

что значит минус перед скобкой? Если переменная не может быть меньше 0

Result получаем вот так:

```
  for Byte in TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(Text) do
  begin
    Result := Result xor Byte;
```

так что не думаю что там может быть минус, я в delphi не силён так что могу много чего не знать.

Comment: Это унарный минус, применяемый к целочисленному типу

Comment: а как если число то не может быть меньше 0 так как эта cardinal

Comment: Операция унарный минус не обязательно предполагает, что число должно после нее становиться отрицательным. Оно может работать как 2-complement flip для знакового целого, но результат остается беззнаковым.

Comment: случайно не знаешь как такое реализовать в c#, или объясните что такео cardinal как он работает то? что эта за волшебное число

Comment: Обычный унарный минус в C# так же работает.

Comment: Неужели не получается в отладчике по строчкам пройти и посмотреть что там делается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типа `Cardinal` в Delphi это синоним типа `unsigned int` из C/C++. 4-байтовое беззнаковое целое.

`(Result and 1)` может иметь только два значения: 1 или 0.

Применение унарного минуса к 0 даст 0, то есть число `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000b`.

Применение унарного минуса к 1 даст -1, то есть число `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111b`.

В итоге вы получаете значение, у которого все биты соответствуют младшему биту значения Result.